# Best strategy for evolving API response format

Tags: rest

### Scenario

- You are operating and developing code for a REST API server.
- There are many clients using your service, including one client that you also develop.
- The API response currently contains some fields containing dates in 'DD-MM-YYYY' format. For example,

  ```json
  {
    "header": {"...": "..."},
    "content": {
      "quote": "The Darkness of Mere Being",
      "dates": ["13-01-1987", "01-01-1963"]
    }
  }
  ```
- You wish to transition the API into giving date in [ISO 8601](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952652/1818110) format without upsetting existing clients.

### Question

- What is the best practice or strategy of making changes to API in such scenario?

  Please try to make answer generally applicable.
- How is the example solution below? Anything to change?

### Example Solution

- Include a flag in JSON response to help client detect new format. For example,

  ```json
  {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "header": {
       "...": "...",
       "flags": {
         "dateformat": "ISO 8601"
       }
    },
    "content": {
      "quote": "The Darkness of Mere Being",
      "dates": ["1987-01-13", "1963-01-01"]
    }
  }
  ```
- Make new API available at different endpoint, at a different prefix like `domain.com/v2/...`.
- On the client side, instead of making a different build for each version, support both format for a time. Check for the flag and process API response differently according to the flag.

Comment: It's pretty common to version APIs by putting version numbers in the URI. `/v1/some_endpoint` then later `/v2/some_endpoint1`. This means you need to maintain early versions for clients who are slow to change, but allows you to make changes without breaking existing code. I'm note sure including the version as a JSON field really helps since clients will need to change code to read and adjust to that change.